# Move files shell script

Tags: shell-script, rename, mv

I have a shell script `ren.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mv /home/imp/imp/msgs/$1.PK1 /home/imp/imp/msgs/$1.BRD
/usr/bin/mv /home/imp/imp/msgs/$1.PK2 /home/imp/imp/msgs/$1.MIX
```

It works fine, but it only moves 2 files at a time (`*.PK2` and `*.PK1`).
I'd like for it to move all existing `*.PK1` and `*.PK2` files to `*.MIX`and `*.BRD` files

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
for name in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.PK1; do
    mv "$name" "${name%.PK1}.BRD"
done

for name in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.PK2; do
    mv "$name" "${name%.PK2}.MIX"
done
```

The first loop will iterate over all `*.PK1` files under `/home/imp/imp/msgs` and replace the filename suffix with `.BRD`.

The second loop does the analogous thing with the other set of files.

The variable expansion `${name%.PK2}.MIX` will remove the string `.PK2` from the end of the value stored in the variable `name` and then append the string `.MIX` to the end of the result of that.

Comment: @ignatius Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat - <<\eof | make -f - SRCDIR="/home/imp/imp/msgs"
.PHONY:all force
all:$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.PK[12]);
%.PK1:force;/usr/bin/mv "$@" "$(@:.PK1=.BRD)";
%.PK2:force;/usr/bin/mv "$@" "$(@:.PK2=.MIX)";
eof
```

The cat command builds a makefile on the fly. The targets `all` and `force` are phony => target will always be rebuilt, in our case, `mv` is run each time. The `$(wildcard ...)` builds up a list of all the required `*.PK1, *.PK2` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- "BRD" "MIX"
for src in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.PK[12]; do
   eval "dest=\${src%.*}.\${${src#${src%?}}}"
   /usr/bin/mv "$src" "$dest"
done
```

The underlying idea is we store the mapping of src filename extension into the new extension by means of "$@" array.

`$src` contains `name.PK1`
`${src%.*}` contains `name`
`${src#${src%?}}` contains `1`
thus `dest` is evaluated to  "name" "." "BRD" = "name.BRD"